# Every homomorphic image of abelian group is abelian but converse need not be true.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Every  homomorphic image  of abelian  group is  abelian but converse  need  not be  true.

My  exercise is  to give an counterexample  that  converse  need not be true.

My attempt  :  I tried to construct a  mapping  $f : S_3 \rightarrow  \frac{S_3}{A_3}$ defined by $f(x) = x$ where $ x \in S_3$

I thinks  this  will  be  counter example  but here $S_3$  is non- abelian.

Is  jt true?

Comment: Just take the trivial map from $S_3$ to the trivial group. It is a group homomorphism, but $S_3$ is non-abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have written $f(x)=xA_3$, as that's what the elements of $S_3/A_3$ look like. But otherwise, yeah, that's a good example. This $f$ (and all other homomorphisms constructed from a group to a quotient of that group in this way) is called the *canonical quotient homomorphism*. Because it's the most obvious way to map a group into a quotient.

For an even simpler example, take *any* non-abelian group and map it to the trivial group (or to the identity element of your favourite group).

Comment: good   logics @ARthur  Sir

Answer (score 2):

A well known example is the determinant mapping from the invertible $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ ($GL(n,\mathbb{R})$) to the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$

$$\det:  GL(n,R) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$$

Answer (score -1):

Another  counter example  from trancelocation answer . $$\det:  GL(n,R) \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$$

Comment: For a moment I thought you have invented the trancelocation homomorphism.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  yes,,,i  was thinking more  about  trancelocation  example.....finally  i found  that  example    which  i have  wriiten above